# Remove the microseconds from a timedelta object

Tags: python, datetime, format, timedelta

I do a calculation of average time, and I would like to display the resulted average without microseconds.

```
avg = sum(timedeltas, datetime.timedelta(0)) / len(timedeltas)
```

Comment: What is 'datetimes'... a list of timedeltas? If so, the sum returns a timedelta object including microseconds... so what's the problem?

Comment: `avg.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, but it will return string.

Comment: @tdelaney I changed the name of the variable from `datetimes` to `timedeltas`, as I agree that it is meant to be a list of timedeltas

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Take the timedelta and remove its own microseconds, as microseconds and read-only attribute:

```
avg = sum(timedeltas, datetime.timedelta(0)) / len(timedeltas)
avg = avg - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=avg.microseconds)
```

You can make your own little function if it is a recurring need:

```
import datetime

def chop_microseconds(delta):
    return delta - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=delta.microseconds)
```

I have not found a better solution.

Answer (score 68):

If it is just for the display, this idea works :

```
avgString = str(avg).split(".")[0]
```

The idea is to take only what is before the point.
It will return **01:23:45** for **01:23:45.1235**

Comment: this one is stupid simple and awesome. should be considered the best answer imho

Answer (score 20):

another option, given timedelta you can do:

```
avg = datetime.timedelta(seconds=math.ceil(avg.total_seconds()))
```

You can replace the `math.ceil()`, with `math.round()` or `math.floor()`, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 9):

```
c -= timedelta(microseconds=c.microseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) only stores days, seconds and microseconds internally, you can construct a new timedelta without microseconds:

```
from datetime import timedelta
timedeltas = [
    timedelta(hours=1, minutes=5, seconds=30, microseconds=9999), 
    timedelta(minutes=35, seconds=17, microseconds=55), 
    timedelta(hours=2, minutes=17, seconds=3, microseconds=1234),
]
avg = sum(timedeltas, timedelta(0)) / len(timedeltas) # timedelta(0, 4756, 670429)
avg = timedelta(days=avg.days, seconds=avg.seconds) # timedelta(0, 4756)
```

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, creating a new timedelta with the days and seconds explicitly from the old is not more or less hackish than subtracting the microseconds using another newly created timedelta. This is what I would do at least.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to get the last minutes without microseconds:

```
import time
import datetime
NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
LASTMINUTE =  NOW - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds = NOW.second, microseconds = NOW.microsecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Hobbestigrou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18470628/) is okay but it doesn't round. If you want one that leverages [`pandas.Timedelta.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.round.html), here it is:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

td = datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=23, seconds=45, microseconds=678901)
print(td, repr(td))
1:23:45.678901 datetime.timedelta(seconds=5025, microseconds=678901)

td2 = pd.Timedelta(td).round('s').to_pytimedelta()
print(td2, repr(td2))
1:23:46 datetime.timedelta(seconds=5026)
```

Similarly, if you would prefer to floor instead, there is [`pandas.Timedelta.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.floor.html).

Answer (score -1):

I found this to work for me:

```
start_time = datetime.now()
some_work()
end time = datetime.now()
print str(end_time - start_time)[:-3]
```

Output:

```
0:00:01.955
```

I thought about this after searching in https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: As mentioned in countless other threads here on stackoverflow, this is not a good idea, as (1) not all timedelta objects are displayed with 6 characters (see the 0 time delta) for the microssecond part and (2) this does not deal with any form of rounding.